# How to convert UTC to IST conversion in apex?

Tags: datetime, convert

I am getting the time as string like `"client_modified": "2020-02-04T11:27:34Z"`
How can I convert this to local time zone,

**Update:**

I am getting this time from api response I need to display it in lightning:formatteddatetime, Sort those records based on date time so am doing this conversion in controller side

**code:**

```
string s = string.valueof(a2.get('server_modified'));
DateTime LDate = null;
if(s != null && s != ''){
    s = s.replace('T', ' ');
    s = s.replace('Z', '');
    LDate = DateTime.valueof(s);
}
```

Comment: In most situations, you don't need to do anything. Salesforce stores datetimes in UTC, and converts to whatever the user's locale is when displayed on something like a page layout or visualforce page (if you're using `<apex:outputField>`). You should [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: @DerekF Updated

Comment: so does the order change if you change the timezone and then sort with datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Derek mentioned, Salesforce store the time in UTC but when we use apex:outputfield in VF page, Salesforce convert the datetime to based on user locale so you don't need to do anything.

If you still have any other use case then I suggest use below code to convert

Use Date.format() method and pass the time Zone. It will convert the time for you

```
//Get current date time in GMT format
Datetime dt = System.now();

//Convert it into Indian Standard Time(dtIST).
String dtIST = dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'IST');

System.debug('dt-' + dt);
System.debug('dtIST-' + dtIST);
```

Comment: I am getting date time as string from api response, so I wanted to convert it into date time

Comment: please check the code i updated

Comment: please check updated code @Ratan Paul

Comment: @nubie Can you give the value of a2.get('server_modified') ?

Comment: 2020-02-04T11:27:34Z @Ratan Paul